# Characterizing subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Tags: vector-spaces

I recall from linear algebra that subspaces of say $\mathbb{R}^2$ are of the form $\{\vec{0}\}$, $\mathbb{R}^2$, or lines through the origin. Does this characterization extend for all $\mathbb{R}^n$ and if so does anyone know a good reference for how all this works? In particular is there some sort of algebraic form that all these subspaces come in? For example can they all be written as solutions to homogeneous systems of linear equations?

Comment: A subspace is also a vector space, and therefore has to contain the additive identity. Therefore, if they are solutions to systems of linear equations, they must be homogeneous (contain the 0 element).

Comment: A quick google search turns up this reference. I believe it answers your question quite adequately. https://math.okstate.edu/people/binegar/3013-S99/3013-l07.pdf

Comment: In $\mathbb R^3$, you can also have *planes* through the origin, and in general for $\mathbb R^n$, *hyperplanes* through the origin.